# Unable to Interact with Prompt Dialog Box in Selenium WebDriver Using Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am facing an issue while trying to interact with a prompt dialog box using Selenium Web-driver in Python.

I am automating a website where a prompt dialog box is automatically triggered upon opening the URL.
The prompt dialog box contains two input fields for username and password, along with "Sign In" and "Cancel" buttons.

I am unable to input the username and password into the prompt dialog box using Selenium WebDriver.
Despite trying various methods to locate and interact with the input fields and buttons, the code does not seem to have any effect.

[image]

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver.get(url)

prompt_dialog = driver.switch_to.alert
prompt_dialog.send_keys(f"{decrypted_username}\t{decrypted_password}")

prompt_dialog.accept()
```